# Which files of a libGDX HTML project belong into the repository?

Tags: git, gwt, repository, libgdx

I develop a web app using the libGDX framework. My question is, which directories of the libGDX HTML project belong in my repository?

I don't think I need to push the `gwt-unitCache`-directory in my repo, right? I'm confused about the `war`-directory, since it also contains the `WEB-INF` directory and configuration files. Anyway, are there any sub-directories of the war directory which do not belong in my repository?

See screen below, it shows the default project structure of the libGDX HTML project. I've highlighted a few directories I'm not sure about, see comments below. I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple rule: Anything that can be re-generated shouldn't be part of a Git repo.

That means: if you can clone you repo, launch a build command, and end up with the same war folder than the one you are illustrating in your question, then you don't need to add that folder to your repo.

For instance, the official [.gitgignore for the `libgdx` project itself](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/.gitignore) does include:

```
war/
```

Comment: I know this rule. However I never used the libGDX-html before, so I have no experiences which files I would need to modify manually in the future, e.g. I don't know if I will ever need to change the `web.xml` in war directory manually, or if I would change that in the libGDX main project and it would generate the files in the libGDX-html project. If I exclude the war directory from repo, I might get problems in future. Please be more specific on my type of project, means on projects using the libGDX framework.

Comment: @Michael the idea of any war folder is that you don't modify directly in it. You modify files which will be used to generate the war folder. It is a packaging folder meant for distribution, not to be modified.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. It's been a while since I worked with projects which use a war directory, e.g. JSF projects, that's why I was confused. I remember that JSF projects generate the web.xml, thought they generate it into war directory, but I might be wrong with that.

Comment: @Michael that is the general idea, illustrated by http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/56799 (mentioned by e4thdog)